# flush_rewrite_rules breaks permalinks

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

Over the last few month I experienced that about 2-3 times a month the permalinks of one of my site are not working any more.

Tested a few things and found out that when executing `flush_rewrite_rules();` the permalinks are broken and are back after visiting the permalinks settings page.

The htaccess file looks normally:

```
# WordPress
###########################
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

It's really strange. Any idea what this could be?

Additionally what's the excact function being executed when visiting the permalinks settings page? Thought it would be at least `flush_rewrite_rules(false)` but executing this manually doesn't help.

Comment: what do you mean by "broken" ? give us more details

Comment: 404 site not found when visiting the urls of course